# TensorFlow JS - saving min/max values alongside model and loading back in beside prediction data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm working on building a ML model using TensorFlow JS. New to JS and ML. I have a working model that makes decent predictions. However when I save the model and load it into a client side UI I also need the original min/max values to normalise to the same amount (I think this is right otherwise I won't be getting the same prediction as the values would be different). I've tried bringing the min/max back as individual tensor values and bringing back the full tensor to then be able to loop through and find the min/max. I've also tried hard coding the min max as a number and as an object.

I can see the tensor but can't access min or max. This means I end up with a NaN error when trying to predict. I am new to this and guessing its something very obvious I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Slowly losing the plot trying to work out where I've gone wrong.

```
//saving tensor normalisedFeature to later access min/max used 

    function downloadJ() {

            let values = {
                normalisedFeature
            }
            let json = JSON.stringify(values);
            //Convert JSON string to BLOB.
            json = [json];
            let blob1 = new Blob(json, { data:"text/json;charset=utf-8" }); 
            

            let url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            link = url.createObjectURL(blob1);
            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.download = "tValues.json";
            a.href = link;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }


//loading up tensor saved values
let normalisedFeatureJ = {};
    $.ajax({
        url: "model/tValues.json",
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            normalisedFeatureJ = (data);
        }
    });
console.log(Object.values(normalisedFeatureJ));

//tried dataSync();, looping, parsing etc. Can't get anything to let me access min/max


//json file looks like: 
{"normalisedFeature":
    {"tensor": {"isDisposedInternal":false,"shape":[10000,17],"dtype":"float32","size":170000,"strides":[17],"dataId":{},"id":28,"rankType":"2"},
            "min":{"isDisposedInternal":false,"shape":[],"dtype":"float32","size":1,"strides":[],"dataId":{},"id":6,"rankType":"0"},
                "max":{"isDisposedInternal":false,"shape":[],"dtype":"float32","size":1,"strides":[],"dataId":{},"id":16,"rankType":"0"}}}



//normalise and denormalise functions using tensor maths
function normalise(tensor, previousMin = null, previousMax = null) {
        const min = previousMin || tensor.min();
        console.log("tensor min for normalised is :" + tensor.min());
        const max = previousMax || tensor.max();
        console.log("tensor max for normalised is :" + tensor.max());

        const normalisedTensor = tensor.sub(min).div(max.sub(min));
       // const normalisedTensor = (tensor-min)/(max-min);
        return {
            tensor: normalisedTensor,
            min,
            max
        };
    }

    function denormalise(tensor, min, max) {
        console.log("tensor min for denormalised is :" + min);
        console.log("tensor max for denormalised is :" + max);
        const denormalisedTensor = tensor.mul(max.sub(min)).add(min);
        return denormalisedTensor;
    }
```

I did also try completing the maths without the use of the tensor maths but that was a hot mess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file contains the tensor metadata, but not the data itself. In `downloadJ`, instead define `values` by

```js
let values = {
  tensor: {
    shape: normalisedFeature.tensor.shape,
    data: normalisedFeature.tensor.dataSync()
  },
  min: normalisedFeature.min.dataSync()[0],
  max: normalisedFeature.max.dataSync()[0]
};
```

The JSON will look like

```
{
  "tensor": {
    "shape": [
      10000,
      17
    ],
    "data": {
      "0": 0.6050498485565186,
      ...
      "169999": 0.055848438292741776
    }
  },
  "min": -43.01580047607422,
  "max": 727.2080078125
}
```

This contains the min and max values that you will need when you load the model.